# How to properly save the information from scraping to Postgresql database in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am new to nodejs and I have a scraper and I want to save the array to my postgresql database.
The issue is that in my current code appending the array is faster than scraping and this means I append an empty array to database and I get empty fields in the database.

How can I make it happen that scraping has to be finished first then the appending?

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");
const match_data = []

const url = "https://www.covers.com/sports/nba/matchups?selectedDate=2023-03-08"

const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool({
  user: ###,
  host: ###,
  database: ###,
  password: ###,
  port: ###
});


pool.query(`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nba_test5(
    id varchar PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    hometeam varchar,
    awayteam varchar,
    homescore varchar,
    awayscore varchar
    )
`);


async function getMatch() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)

        const match_list = $('.cmg_matchup_game_box.cmg_game_data');
        match_list.each(function(){
            match_id = $(this).attr('data-event-id');
            home_team = $(this).attr('data-home-team-fullname-search');
            away_team = $(this).attr('data-away-team-fullname-search');
            home_score = $(this).attr('data-home-score');
            away_score = $(this).attr('data-away-score');

            match_data.push({match_id, home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score})
        });
         

        console.log(match_data);
    }
    
    catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

getMatch();

pool.query('INSERT INTO nba_test5 (id, hometeam, awayteam, homescore, awayscore) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)', [match_data.map(data => data.match_id), match_data.map(data => data.home_team),match_data.map(data => data.away_team), match_data.map(data => data.home_score),match_data.map(data => data.away_score)], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Data inserted successfully');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the `async` funciton call. If you don't, it's not going to wait for the scraping to finish before running the insertion query. See the [MDN await article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for more info.

`getMatch()` -> `await getMatch()`